# Handling Viewmodel on Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, viewmodel

I have been learning .MVC recently and am having trouble understanding how to process a viewmodel when posted back. I have followed the example here: http://www.shawnmclean.com/blog/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-multiple-check-boxes-in-an-array-or-list/#codesyntax_2 My problem is how do we handle the viewmodel when posted back so that a user is save with the correct roles? Do I have to manually pull the values out of the viewmodel and assign the selected roles to the user?

All help appreciated!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to. This is the code from the your link handling that.
The Action receives the ViewModel object and calls a Method in some UserService which does the actual work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserRole(UserRoleViewModel model)
{
    List<Role> roles = model.Roles.Where(r => r.IsInRole)
            .Select(r => new Role {RoleId = r.RoleId, RoleName = r.RoleName})
            .ToList();
    userService.AddRolesToUser(model.UserId, roles);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is this method outlined in my link the best way to complete this task? Would there be a way to do this so that the User part of the viewmodel is automatically assigned the selected Roles in the viewmodel?

Comment: Im not sure if i understand your question. The UserRolewViewModel just contains data mapped from fields the http request. All other processing is up to the controllers action method.